# time elapsed with php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on my review page and I have this this simple question.
how do I change my database result, into "[result x] days/month/years ago"?
it seems like curent date minus(-) post date. but, how do I write it corectly.

thanks for your help.

here is my code,

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews ORDER BY review_code DESC LIMIT 3");
while($db=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

echo "
<div style='padding-bottom: 25px;'>
Post Date: ".$db['post_date']." minus(-) Current Time: ".time()."
</div>
";}
?>
```

the result is

```
Post Date: 2017-06-27 08:00:00 minus(-) Current Time: 1498701679
```

can anyone help me? please..

Comment: Do you mean that you have a date value and you want to translate it into a "time ago" format, similar to how Stack Overflow lists times of questions/comments/etc.?  A Google search for something like "javascript time ago" will get you started with that.  There are small libraries which convert your display values for you.

Comment: Yes.. I did this concept on my javascript. and it works very well, because it doesn't contain any database. it results "a time ago" completly like I want. but, in this case, I'm working with php and database. which is a new things for me. and I dont really understand how to do it.

Comment: Is your PHP code not outputting to a web page?  If so (as most PHP does), then you can use the JavaScript library.

Comment: the output shows the right data. did you mean that ".$db['post_date']." can be convert using javascript?

Comment: I mean that JavaScript doesn't care where the data comes from, it's just going to convert whatever value you give it.  You can hard-code the value for testing, or output it from a database.  To JavaScript it's literally the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

What you should basically do is create two datetime objects and use the diff function:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($db['post_date']); // Date post was created
$datetime2 = new DateTime(); // Default DateTime is now
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('Post created %a days ago');
```

---

If you want to dynamically change wording (days, months, years, etc) check out this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#97880

Comment: it works, but when i changes the post database into 2015, it shows "Post created 547 days ago" how do you convert that into "months ago" and "years ago"? and 1 more question, can we have "if 0 days = today" and "if 1 days = yesterday"?

Answer (score 0):

Dwipa good news.  <strike>PHP has already got functions that do just that.</strike>  The time_elapsed_B function should do what you want.  Here is the article with the information in it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

EDIT
Whoops not built in but provided at link.

```
function time_elapsed_A($secs){
    $bit = array(
        'y' => $secs / 31556926 % 12,
        'w' => $secs / 604800 % 52,
        'd' => $secs / 86400 % 7,
        'h' => $secs / 3600 % 24,
        'm' => $secs / 60 % 60,
        's' => $secs % 60
    );

    foreach($bit as $k => $v)
        if($v > 0)$ret[] = $v . $k;

    return join(' ', $ret);
}


function time_elapsed_B($secs){
    $bit = array(
        ' year'        => $secs / 31556926 % 12,
        ' week'        => $secs / 604800 % 52,
        ' day'        => $secs / 86400 % 7,
        ' hour'        => $secs / 3600 % 24,
        ' minute'    => $secs / 60 % 60,
        ' second'    => $secs % 60
    );

    foreach($bit as $k => $v){
        if($v > 1)$ret[] = $v . $k . 's';
        if($v == 1)$ret[] = $v . $k;
    }
    array_splice($ret, count($ret)-1, 0, 'and');
    $ret[] = 'ago.';

    return join(' ', $ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality to do this. You'd have to write the code manually, to find the diff between now and the date, and convert that in to time units.

However you don't have to re-invent the wheel here. Date manipulation libraries like [Moment](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php) already implement features for this. (Look at the `Moment::calendar()` method)

Comment: If you're gonna use a library, just go with the more popular and widely-used Carbon ;) http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: @theomessin Sure, that's another way to go. I just always preferred this Moment library, because it's essentially the same as it's JavaScript counterpart, and I like the symmetry :)

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to start a lib war cause I've got nothing better to do right now.. XD

Answer (score 0):

The following function was provided by the community at http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php. It returns a human readable representation of a number of seconds. So feed it with the difference in seconds between now and your date.

```
function time_elapsed_B($secs){
    $bit = array(
        ' year'        => $secs / 31556926 % 12,
        ' week'        => $secs / 604800 % 52,
        ' day'        => $secs / 86400 % 7,
        ' hour'        => $secs / 3600 % 24,
        ' minute'    => $secs / 60 % 60,
        ' second'    => $secs % 60
        );

    foreach($bit as $k => $v){
        if($v > 1)$ret[] = $v . $k . 's';
        if($v == 1)$ret[] = $v . $k;
        }
    array_splice($ret, count($ret)-1, 0, 'and');
    $ret[] = 'ago.';

    return join(' ', $ret);
}
```

Example use:

```
$seconds = strtodate($db['post_date']);

echo time_elapsed_B(time() - $seconds);
```